# How to load output data from a print function into a pandas data frame?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that provides me with output values. However, I want those values to be displayed in a pandas data frame.

Function:

```
def print_response(response):


  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print ( header + ': ' + dimension )

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print ('Date range (' + str(i) + ')' )
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print ( metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value )
```

When running the Code, it gives me this Output (I posted only 1 row):
Date: 20180430
Customers: 257917

I want this data a pandas data frame though. 
PLEASE HELP, I AM NEW TO THIS!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. We are not able to run your code as it is.

Comment: Stop printing them and write them somewhere instead (or do both)

Comment: Could you give me an example based on my code please? I am new to this :)